# Smart MOSFETs, logic level input (MOSFET replacement)

Tags: mosfet, automotive

The diesel heater ECU my car uses has an shorted "smart" MOSFET [BTS141](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-BTS141-DS-v01_00-EN.pdf?fileId=5546d46259d9a4bf015a84e19f937577), which drives the glow plug. I don't know much about it since I can't determine the manufacturer. It accepts logic-level input and then switches current to the glow plug (glow plug resistance around 0.3-0.6 Ω cold and increases very fast) for less than a minute I would guess (the glow plug itself is the current limiter etc.).

What should I keep in mind when I'm temporarily trying to replace it with a different MOSFET? I will try to find another BTS141 but right now I need something to test and use for a few weeks. I would have guessed I could just replace it with any MOSFET but seeing as it's a "smart" one I would rather ask first.

[image]

Comment: Can you post a picture of the mosfet? The manufacturer is probably [Infineon](http://www.infineon.com/cms/en/product/power/smart-low-side-and-high-side-switches/low-side-switch/automotive-smart-low-side-switch-hitfet/BTS141/productType.html?productType=db3a30443a06def4013ab74184b1278c "Infineon").

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B59LXztPx9NNMTlIS1RrbE1QQmM

Answer (score 1):

This is a Chip on Chip device. Siemons developed the ability to attach a logic  chip to a MOSFET. There first part if my memory is still good was the TempFet which worked similarly on the gate but never really explained that I know about. I do not have a schematic but from what is being said placing a resistor will not fake it out.

The way the chip works is you drive the input through a resistor and measure the pin directly for status with a three pin device which you are showing. It is a bi-directional pin that is driven low upon a fault but it still needs energy  from the resistor. You could use a Avalanche Rated MOSFET as a short term substitute for it. Lower RDSon should only help and keep it cooler. This is well explained on the siemens data sheet if you can find one. The part was picked up by infineon and is not on the do not design with list. Let us know how you do.

Answer (score 0):

According to the first datasheet on Google, it has some logic for over current and other scenarios, a built in flyback diode and good for logic level inputs. You could put a regular n-channel mosfet there,  but we don't know if the board checks for the short circuit feedback signal.

My Camry has a solenoid that is bad. I tried to trick the ecu with a power resistor. Didn't work. The ecu, despite what the service manual says, checks for the collapse of the inductance field to make sure the solenoid is working. Your car may be equally smart.

Comment: It does check for short circuit but it also uses the glow plug for resistance  with the transistor in OFF mode(measures glow plug temperature when it is running and also serves flame detector purpose). So it has a seperate circuit for that. Right now it gave open circuit fault becausethe mosfet was stuck closed(short -d)so the obvious seperate feedback system saw that the 12V was still on the glowplug so it thought it was open circuit as it didnt saw any voltage drop. That is my theory at least and i looked at some schematics.

Comment: Shouldnt the new mosfet be logic level also aka 1.7-2.3v instead of 2-4v?

Comment: Yes, it should conform with the gate voltage and RDS of the original. Or build a mosfet driver circuit.

Comment: The mosfet is built by Siemens. I actually found correct document: http://info.incomp.hu/NETPDF/BTS141.pdf

Comment: Looks like siemens and infineon chips are exactly the same, just spun off company. Well i ordered the original infineon chip since it will probably arrive in 2-3 days...